# After I merge two branches, the `diff` command shows me that the two branches are still different

Tags: git

I am working on two branches and now I want to merge them.

So I did this:

```
git checkout MainBranch
git merge SubBranch
```

That command runs fine.

But now, if I do this:

```
diff MainBranch SubBranch
```

it shows me differences in the code between the 2 branches.

Shouldn't the merge make them the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the merge make them the same?

No. After a true merge, one branch (the one that was merged) is one commit behind the other — because the merge commit is on one branch only (the one that was merged into). If you have this:

```
x --- y --- z (main)
 \
  a --- b (branch)
```

Then if you are on `main` and you merge `branch`, you have this:

```
x --- y --- z --- m (main)
 \             /
  a --- b (branch)
```

A merge commit (`m`) was added to `main`, but nothing about `branch` was changed.

Under some circumstances, Git may do a "fast-forward" when you ask to merge (or pull), in which case the two branches become momentarily identical. But a fast-forward is not a true merge.

Comment: For more, read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/